# What is the meaning of the +4?

Tags: theory, lead-sheets

I bought a music sheet last year and came across this symbol. What does +4 mean?

[image]

Here are the details of the song.

[image]

Comment: Really need more context - what song, what key, surrounding bars, other numbers similar?

Comment: Plus fours are breeches or trousers that extend four inches (10 cm) below the knee.  (I can't resist lateral jokes)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - surely plus fours are vertical jokes..?

Comment: @Tim    so true.   And don't call me Shirley

Comment: could be a lot of things, as Tim notes. Context!

Comment: Seems to be in the section of the chords so likely not related to the note but the previous chord. So no idea if Eflat +4 makes any sense

Answer (score 2):

Without a clef or key signature, we are only guessing.  But if we were to assume E-flat major, treble clef, this is showing us that the second note is the raised fourth degree of the scale.  (Usually the fourth degree would be A-flat, but this is negated by the natural sign).